# Go: declaring a slice inside a struct?

Tags: go, struct, slice

I have the following code:

```
type room struct {
    width float32
    length float32
}
type house struct{
    s := make([]string, 3)
    name string
    roomSzSlice := make([]room, 3)
} 

func main() {


}
```

And when i try to build and run it i get the following errors:

```
c:\go\src\test\main.go:10: syntax error: unexpected :=
c:\go\src\test\main.go:11: non-declaration statement outside function body
c:\go\src\test\main.go:12: non-declaration statement outside function body
c:\go\src\test\main.go:13: syntax error: unexpected }
```

What did i do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: just declare it like the other fields. "s []string" in this case; the error pretty clearly tells you what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but if i declare it like you said, what's the difference between a slice declaration and an array declaration?

Comment: one thing is that part of the *type* of an array is it's length, so an array of 3 elements is not the same type as an array of 4 elements, so if you declare an array such as var n [3]int then you have an array of 3 ints, with slice in the same context you write: var []int, without giving the length. I want to say just don't worry about arrays; really they aren't directly useful to us in nearly all cases.

Comment: *make* does let you does let you specify a length and capacity for a slice but those can both change. When you use make Go creates an unnamed array and returns a slice of it, which is then your only means of accessing that array directly. If you outgrow the array then Go can make you a new, larger one and your slice will now point to it.

Comment: @Snowman Forgive me, but I can not agree with the statement that arrays are not directly useful, let alone in nearly all cases. For any IO based on fixed size, arrays are the _only_ way to go. Speaking of fixed sizes, circular buffers come to my mind, too.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg. Fair enough. I'm not saying they don't serve a purpose but I've yet to need one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off you cannot assign/initialize inside the struct. The := operator declares and assigns. You can however, achieve the same result simply.

Here is a simple, trivial example that would do roughly what you're trying:

```
type house struct {
    s []string
}

func main() {
    h := house{}
    a := make([]string, 3)
    h.s = a
}
```

I've never written one that way, but if it servers your purpose... it compiles anyway.

Answer (score 7):

You can *declare* a slice in a struct declaration, but you can not initialize it. You have to do this by different means.

```
// Keep in mind that lowercase identifiers are
// not exported and hence are inaccessible
type House struct {
    s []string
    name string
    rooms []room
}

// So you need accessors or getters as below, for example
func(h *House) Rooms()[]room{
    return h.rooms
}

// Since your fields are inaccessible, 
// you need to create a "constructor"
func NewHouse(name string) *House{
    return &House{
        name: name,
        s: make([]string, 3),
        rooms: make([]room, 3),
    }
}
```

Please see the above as a **<kbd>[runnable example on Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/5bzAZhohcD)</kbd>**

---

**EDIT**

To Initialize the struct partially, as requested in the comments, one can simply change

```
func NewHouse(name string) *House{
    return &House{
        name: name,
    }
}
```

Please see the above as a **<kbd>[runnable example on Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/He_sznEsG0)</kbd>**, again

Comment: Thanks, but if i don't want to initialize the slice (meaning - i don't want to specify the number of elements in it), how would i do it?

Comment: <del>Simply remove the number in make, like `s: make([]string)`.</del>  It might be a good idea to retake [tour.golang.org](http://tour.golang.org) , and reading [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) surely does not hurt, even if it is the second or third time.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg that won't work - slice length is required as an argument to `make`.

@Gambit2007 - if you don't want to initialize it, then just leave it as its zero value (remove the initialization entirely). It will be nil, and will have a length of 0. You can initialize it later if you want.

Comment: @joshlf Taking my own advice. Thank you.

Comment: so you mean like this: s []string? wouldn't that just be an array declaration?

Comment: @Gambit2007 Please see my edit. Please be also advised that SO is not a forum. Instead of refining your question in the comments to answers, it is better to edit the original question to better reflect your requirements. However, it _does_ make sense to ping the participants about the update, of course.

Answer (score -1):

You can also refer this: https://golangbyexample.com/struct-slice-field-go/

```
type student struct {
    name   string 
    rollNo int    
    city   string 
}

type class struct {
    className string
    students  []student
}

goerge := student{"Goerge", 35, "Newyork"}
john := student{"Goerge", 25, "London"}

students := []student{goerge, john}

class := class{"firstA", []student{goerge, john}}
```